# Am trying to get the live Price and change of stock from a yahoo finance and its not working ..it returns the else statement

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd 
import datetime 
import requests
from requests.exceptions import ContentDecodingError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



##the fucntion to help find the information from the url below.
def web_content_div(web_content, class_path):
    web_content_div  = web_content.find_all('div', {'class': class_path})
    try:
        
        spans = web_content_div[0].find_all('span')
        texts = [span.get_text() for span in spans]
        
    except IndexError:
        
        texts = []
    
    return texts
# the Function to get the information from the URL
def real_time_price(stock_code):
    url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + stock_code + '?p=' + stock_code + '&.tsrc=fin-srch'
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        web_content = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        texts = web_content_div(web_content, 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)')
        
        if texts != []:
            price, change = texts[0], texts[1]
        
        else:
              price, change = [], []
            
    except ConnectionError:
        
        price, change = [], []
        
    return price, change

#assing stock = BRK-B
stock_code = ['BRK-B']

print(real_time_price('BRK-B'))
```

Comment: firsr you should edit question and use Ctrl+K to format code. And you should describe problem in question's body, not in title. And if you get error message then you should show it in question (not in comments) as text (not image)

Comment: first you could run it without `try/except` to get full error mesasge. And next time you could at least display error - ie. `except ConnectionError as ex: print(ex)` - to see that there is problem.

Comment: you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. Maybe you have wrong values, or maybe it send different `HTML` - ie. warning for bots/spamers/hacker or some message which explain problem. And you could get url and test in real web browser. If it use `JavaScript` then it can make problem because `requests` and `BS` can't run `JavaScript`

Comment: when I test URL in web browser then I see it use JavaScript - and first it shows page which ask to accept `cookies`. So you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser and click and accept `cookies`. Or maybe you should try Python module `yfinanse`

Comment: code works for me if I use `'My(6px)'` instead of `'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'`. It seems it has problem when you use string has many classes.

Comment: it works with many classes when I use CSS selector `web_content.select('div.My\(6px\).Pos\(r\).smartphone_Mt\(6px\)')`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thank you very much sir. your response help me  .. after using  'My(6px)' the code worked for me .. seems it had problem with the string.